# How to handle Uncaught Error: [nuxt] store/index.js should export a method that returns a Vuex instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store

I have setup a default store in [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) in `store/index.js` as the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store) recommends. When I try to render my app I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [nuxt] store/index.js should export a method that
> returns a Vuex instance.

My `store/index.js` file looks like this:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
import myModule from './myModule'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: () => ({

  }),
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    myModule: myModule
  }
})
export default store
```

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are exporting the Vuex store as a constant, you should export a default method that returns the Vuex store instance.

Your `store/index.js` file should look like this:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
import myModule from './myModule'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default () => new Vuex.Store({
  state: () => ({

  }),
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    myModule: myModule
  }
})
```

Comment: Just realized that this is a self-answered question lol Tell me if you want me to remove my answer.

Comment: Different approach, no harm in letting it there. Thanks for the quick response! @kissu

Answer (score 1):

I do have the following and it's working great.

```js
import { test } from './modules/tasty_module'

const state = () => ({})
const mutations = {}
const actions = {}
const getters = {}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  getters,
  actions,
  modules: {
    testModule: test,
  },
}
```